# Eigenvectors for a sum of diagonal and anti-diagonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, permutations

Consider the case of invertible matrix which is the sum of diagonal and anti-diagonal matrices, e.g.,

$$\begin{bmatrix} \color{red}1 &   0 &  0 &  0 &  \color{red}6 \\ 0 &  \color{red}2 &  0 &  \color{red}7 &  0 \\ 0  & 0 & \color{red}3 &  0 &  0 \\ 0 &  \color{red}8  & 0 & \color{red}4 &  0 \\ \color{red}9 &  0  & 0 & 0 &  \color{red}5\end{bmatrix}$$

Such matrices I name shortly $X$-matrices (even shorter $X$ - do they have more official name?) and it's easy to check that the **sum** of two $X$-matrices is an $X$-matrix.

Also the **product** of two matrices is   an $X$-matrix as

$$X_1X_2=(D_1+A_1)   (D_2+A_2)=(D_1D_2+A_1A_2)+(D_1A_2+A_1D_2)$$

($D,A$ denoted here as diagonal and antidiagonal part of $X$) and product of two diagonal or two anti-diagonal is always diagonal and product of diagonal and anti-diagonal is anti-diagonal.

Further if $X$-matrix is invertible also its **inverse** is an $X$-matrix because inverse can be presented as a polynomial of $X$ from Cayley-Hamilton theorem.

Making calculations I have found **one more property** of these matrices:
i.e. also eigenvectors $v_1, v_2, \dots $ for this type of matrix can be grouped  to make $X$-matrix.
For instance for the matrix listed above we have eigenvectors as colummns of

$$V=\begin{bmatrix}
 \color{red}{-0.730}  &  \color{red}{0.529}   &  0.000  &   0.000   &  0.000 \\
  0.000  &  0.000   &  \color{red}{0.730}  &  \color{red}{-0.633}  &   0.000  \\
  0.000 &   0.000   & 0.000  &   0.000  &  \color{red}{1.000}  \\
  0.000  &   0.000  & \color{red}{-0.683}  &  \color{red}{-0.774}  &  0.000  \\
  \color{red}{0.683} &   \color{red}{0.848}   &  0.000  &   0.000  &   0.000  \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

and it's possible to permute columns in order to obtain  from them an $X$-matrix.

- How this last property can be proved? How  can we prove that there is a permutation of eigenvectors of $X$-matrix which is also an $X$-matrix?
- Could we use for proof the equation $X=VDV^{-1}$ where however $V$, if columns are chosen randomly, can be in the form which is not an $X$-matrix? (but its some permutation supposedly is ...)

Comment: I wonder whether only this fact that X-matrices (invertible) have sum, product and inverse in the form of X-matrices it's sufficient to prove the claim about eigenvectors ... I suppose we can regard them as a group but is this fact solely allows us to infer   about its eigenvectors?

Comment: Your group is essentially a direct product of several copies of $GL(2,\mathbb R)$ (plus one instance of $\mathbb R$, if the size is odd).

Comment: @IvanNeretin What are consequences of it?

Comment: I guess your property is one of the consequences.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I'm rather weak in abstract algebra, maybe it is a solution more grounded in linear algebra ?..

Comment: Well, just reorder the basis vectors so that your X-matrix would become a [block diagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices).

Comment: @IvanNeretin I'm not sure how to do that...Could you present it for the example above?

Comment: Reorder your basis to $(x_1,x_5,x_2,x_4,x_3)$. Then the matrix will be $$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &  6 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\ 
9 &  5 &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
0 &  0 &  2 &  7 &  0 \\
0 &  0 &  8 &  4 &  0 \\
0 &  0 &  0 &  0 &  3 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @IvanNeretin I see, swapping appropriately columns and rows ... probably some permutation matrices allow this, .. it's also seems to be promising,.. have you consider to put this procedure into the answer ? this method is worth to memorize, I assume now that this transformation can be expressed as $B_D=PXP^T$ where $P$ is some the permutation matrix to reconstruct and $B$ is block diagonal matrix of the form you presented.. maybe always when we can find such permutation matrix which makes block diagonal matrix -  eigenvectors can be grouped to the original form of matrix...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your X-matrices are actually a pretty well known family in disguise: [block diagonal matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices) with blocks $2\times2$. Go read that paragraph in Wikipedia, it is pretty short, and whatever you need from it is shorter yet:

> The eigenvalues and eigenvectors of ${A}$ are simply those of $A_{1}$ and $A_{2}$ and ... and $A_{n}$ (combined).

Indeed, in an X-matrix, $x_1$ interacts only with $x_n$, $x_2$ with $x_{n-1}$, and so on. Why wouldn't you reorder your basis vectors so as to put the interacting ones next to each other? With your $5\times5$ example, this implies reordering the basis as $(x_1,x_5,x_2,x_4,x_3)$. The matrix which does that is $$P=\begin{pmatrix}1& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 1\\
0& 1& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 1& 0\\
0& 0& 1& 0& 0\end{pmatrix}$$
Now apply that to your matrix $X$ and get
$$PXP^T=\begin{pmatrix}1& 6& 0& 0& 0\\
9& 5& 0& 0& 0\\
0& 0& 2& 7& 0\\
0& 0& 8& 4& 0\\
0& 0& 0& 0& 3
\end{pmatrix}$$
Q.e.d.

Comment: Thank you Ivan for the most general answer. I suppose we can even generalize the case for  more matrices "in disguise", but probably these so-called X-matrices are the most interesting from the structural point of view..

Comment: Additionaly your solution is very compact   as we can, I suppose, write using $P: \ \ \\ \ $ $PXP^T=(PVP^T)(PDP^T)(PVP^T)$ $ \\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ ... I'm very glad you decided to present this solution..

Answer (score 1):

Hint. In your 5x5 matrix, you can easily observe that there ALWAYS exist:

a. Two eigenvectors of the form $u=(x,0,0,0,y)$ - because $Au=(x',0,0,0,y')$

b. Two eigenvectors of the form $v=(0,x,0,y,0)$ - because $Av=(0,x',0,y',0)$ and

c. the eigenvector $(0,0,1,0,0)$.

Put them together as columns and obtain an X-matrix.

Comment: Yes, such observations can be made.. but why is so and why exactly two? Not any other would be appropriate?  What is the explanation of this fact?   How to extend this for any dimension ?

Comment: Maybe I would go in the direction you are proposing, it seems to be promising..